# Extend javascript function without overriding current function body

Tags: javascript, inheritance

Have one function as following

```
function JsFunction(){
//some logic already done by framework library...
}
```

Now, I want to add extra login on that JsFunction
when I call it will perform its logic done before + the logic I added in it.
I don't want to duplicate same logic from library and then add my own code. 
so, how can I achieve that with same function name JsFunction()??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**If** the work the function does is synchronous, it's really easy to wrap it (see below). If it does its work *asynchronously*, you may or may not still be able to wrap it, the details will vary depending on the implementation of the function.

Wrapping a function that works synchonrously:

```
var original = JsFunction;
JsFunction = function JsFunction() {
    // Do stuff before
    // ...
    // Call it
    var result = original.apply(this, arguments);
    // Do stuff after
    // ...
    return result; // Or something else if you prefer
};
```

The meat of that is

```
var result = original.apply(this, arguments);
```

...which uses [`Function#apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) to call the original function with the same `this` that your replacement was called with and all arguments it was called with (`arguments` is a special pseudo-array in JavaScript containing the arguments used when calling a traditional function or method).

With ES2015+ features, you could replace the use of `arguments` with a rest parameter:

```
var original = JsFunction;
JsFunction = function JsFunction(...args) {
    // Do stuff before
    // ...
    // Call it
    var result = original.apply(this, args);
    // Do stuff after
    // ...
    return result; // Or something else if you prefer
};
```

Comment: that's what I exactly wanted.

Answer (score 2):

Copy the old function, then create a new function which calls it (passing in any arguments and the right context), captures the return value, does something else, then returns the return value.

```
(function () { // In an IIFE to avoid creating a global variable
    let oldJsFunction = JsFunction;
    JsFunction = function JsFunction() {
        let return_value = oldJsFunction.apply(this, arguments);
        console.log("… and another thing");
        return return_value;
    }
)());
```

Comment: I think you have a mistake here : `JsFunction = function JsFunction() {` => `JsFunction = function() {` ?

Comment: @Sam: It's fine, it's a *named function expression*.

Comment: @Sam — The original function had a name, I don't see why its replacement should be anonymous.

Comment: @Quentin: It won't be on any modern JavaScript engine, even if you use an anonymous function expression. But there's no reason not to use a named one as you have. :-)

Comment: Ah ok yep :+1:, my bad ;)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder — I haven't properly internalised the rules for implicit names yet, so am rather hesitant to depend on them :)

Comment: @Quentin: :-) Fair enough, and again, no reason *not* to use an NFE in 2018. Re implicit names: The only gotcha is that `obj.foo = function() { }` does *not* assign a name. Almost any other assignment or initialization will.

Comment: What if JsFunction has parameter?
actually I want to do it with bootstrap "modal('show') " function

Comment: @UttamUghareja — That's the point of `apply(this, arguments);`